# Microservice per data model

Tags: architecture, microservices

I have an architectural question about microservices. We have 2 different data sources (2 tables with some simmilar fields but no connection between them). We want only to read data from these. Is it good practice to create a microservice (along it's model object) per each of these sources or it's enough to create a generic model with a generic service which will serve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is it depends on the project/product and needs.

Microservices are arranged around business capabilities. This gives the service context which helps developers consume it. Generic services does not have this context.

For example assume we have two tables one with customer information one with employee information(for simplicity sake). We are only reading from the tables.

A microservice architecture will give you two services both with a read operation.

Thus a developers would call a customer.listAll() if you will and a employee.listAll() for example. However the context is clear.

Using a generic service might result in the following code:
service.listAll(customers). The parameter now carries the context. IN a system with a large amount of different types/tables this can become a major hasssles to call. A generic service would not have service.listCustomers() or service.listEmployees() that is specific and not generic.

Remember an API that is not easy to understand is not easy to use and generic service while initially a bit easier to construct will eventually add complexity. Maintenance not development is the longest and most expensive part of software.

This touches on another point. Having everything in a generic service means that if there is a bug in the customer service we have to stop the employee service too to fix it. The bug can also potentially affect both services. Microservices does not suffer from this as it allows you to take a service down without bringing down the application.

One thing to keep in mind is that you could use a generic pattern to implement your microservice. In other words both the employee and customer service could use a DOA pattern in their operations. The code could be shared between them in some way maybe a library but they would be independent completely still.

Comment: Thank You very much for the detailed answer!